# Having trouble joining properly in bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to grab some information from a first table and then link it to some demographic information I have.

```
SELECT
  colA,
  colB,
  DATE(serverTimeStamp) AS newDate,
  eventType,
  pgSource,
  COUNT(*) FROM (
  SELECT
    *,
    MAX(IF(LOWER(parameters.name)="pagesource", parameters.value, NULL)) WITHIN RECORD AS pgSource
  FROM
    TABLE_DATE_RANGE(mytableA, TIMESTAMP('2016-02-02 00:00:00'), TIMESTAMP('2016-02-02 23:59:59')) )
WHERE
  LOWER(parameters.name)="Allison"
GROUP BY
  parameters.name,
  parameters.value,
  newDate,
  eventType,
  pgSource
```

However, adding a new table changes my results (the count should be the same). It's the first table's results that has the right data.

```
SELECT

  colA,
  colB
  DATE(serverTimeStamp) AS newDate,
  eventType,
  UD.gender,
  UD.locationKey
  pgSource,

  COUNT(distinct instanceId) FROM (

  SELECT
    *,
    MAX(IF(LOWER(parameters.name)="Allison", parameters.value, NULL)) WITHIN RECORD AS pgSource
  FROM
    TABLE_DATE_RANGE(myTableA, TIMESTAMP('2016-02-02 00:00:00'), TIMESTAMP('2016-02-02 23:59:59')) ) EV

join each
  replicated.UserDimension AS UD
ON
  UD.userId = EV.userId


WHERE
  LOWER(parameters.name)="isfirstcontact"

GROUP EACH BY
  colA,
 colB,
  newDate,
  eventType,
  pgSource,
  UD.gender,
  UD.locationKey
```

Any tips on how I can approach this?

**
Mikhail has kindly reminded me that having multiple userIds on the first table will throw my count off. How do I adjust for this fact?

Answer (score 2):

> Any tips?

Just to give you an idea - run below and see difference

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(*), 
  COUNT(1), 
  COUNT(instanceId), 
  COUNT(DISTINCT instanceId) 
FROM
  (SELECT NULL AS instanceId),
  (SELECT 1 AS instanceId),
  (SELECT 2 AS instanceId),
  (SELECT 1 AS instanceId),
```

And, I recommend you to check difference between [COUNT([DISTINCT] ...)](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#countdistinct) and [EXACT_COUNT_DISTINCT()](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#exact_count_distinct)

Another direction to look into - check if you have dup userId (multiple rows for the same userId) on any side  - this also can be a source of count mismatch

Comment: Thanks Mikhail! I do have duplicate userIds - is there any way to adjust for this fact when counting?

Comment: Honestly, it is hard to suggest more without details on first table and w/o understanding what it is that you are trying to do. i suggest to check first part of my answer too

Comment: I just realized  - your two  queries are totally different!! See lines with the conditions for parameters.name! How you expect to have matching counts here?